# glGenQueries always return non-query objects, glBeginQuery return error

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glew, occlusion

I'm trying to create an occlusion query using openGL 3.3, using GLFW, GLEW

load function:

```
uint32_t glQueryID;
glGenQueries(1, &glQueryID);
if (glIsQuery(glQueryID)) //just for testing its always false !
{
 ... it must be always true !?!
}
```

draw function:

```
glBeginQuery(GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED, glQueryID);
glGetError();// 1282 invalid operation
```

However all my other glCalls worked correctly without any error

Running on Mac OS X, intel HD 4000

Comment: Is there some reason why you insist on asking OpenGL if it did the thing you told it to do?

Comment: Don't you love OpenGL, where calling `glGenFoo` doesn't generate any `Foo`, only binding / using them for the first time actually does?

Comment: Hahahaha, yes i love it, and yes that is the reason ! thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [`glIsQuery`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glIsQuery.xhtml):

> glIsQuery returns GL_TRUE if id is currently the name of a query object. If id is zero, or is a non-zero value that is not currently the name of a query object, or if an error occurs, glIsQuery returns GL_FALSE.
>
> A name returned by glGenQueries, but not yet associated with a query object by calling glBeginQuery, is not the name of a query object.

Since you call `glIsQuery` before assinging a query object to it (for example by calling `glBeginQuery`), the return value has to be `GL_FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks very much, 
I would mention that the problem was solved by initialize the query with empty begin and end .. i don't know what was the cause of invalid operation error

    `glGenQueries(1, &glQueryID); 
    glBeginQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED, glQueryID);
    glEndQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by initializing query followed by empty begin/end Query

```
glGenQueries(1, &glQueryID);
glBeginQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED, glQueryID);
glEndQuery(GL_SAMPLES_PASSED);
```

this will fix error 1282 (invalid operation) when drawing later